# StaQover, a new S-O. profile viewer in QML2

Tags: app, qml

As I couldn't find any Chrome extension fitting my needs, I started a QML app to provide just what I need, here it is : StaQover can view a profile by name, and show reputation history and badges !

ATM it is not a standalone app, but the persons who are using Qt5 SDK can test it using the `qmlscene` tool in this SDK to launch the .qml file.

[image: Screenshot of the app]

You can download the QML file on my DropBox here :

[QML application file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1237695/StackOverflowQml.qml)

Comment: +1 Wow - it's nice to see a Qt5/QML app. I would strongly suggest looking into using version control for keeping track of the code. I host a number of my projects on [GitHub](http://github.com) and [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net).

Comment: i'm using Gitorious : https://gitorious.org/staqoverme/staqoverme

Comment: repo has moved here : https://gitorious.org/apps-4-me/staq-me

Answer (score 2):

New release : now it can handle all Stack Exchange network !

[image: Screenshot of new release]

[Still the same link to download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1237695/StackOverflowQml.qml)

Answer (score 2):

Another release :

- bug/perfs fixes
- graphical enhancements
- now shows more info about user
- tells when user is not found on the current site

[image: Screenshot of the last version]

[Here for downloading](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1237695/StackOverflowQml.qml)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another release :

- fixed badge counter (take in account multiple time same badge)
- make multiple awards appear on badge
- summary of gold/silver/bronze
- text layout enhancement
- some bug fixes
- a time count for next refresh (in geeky way)

Enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

You can now download the new releases with C++ launcher included on Gitorious :

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/staqoverme/staqoverme.git
```

For web interface : `https://gitorious.org/staqoverme/staqoverme`

Enjoy !

Comment: DropBox file is no more available BTW

Comment: If you want direct link to .qml file only, use http://gitorious.org/staqoverme/staqoverme/blobs/raw/master/ui.qml

Comment: repo has moved : https://gitorious.org/apps-4-me/staq-me

Answer (score 2):

New release available on Gitorious :

- lot of fixes, speed enhancement
- a geeky and eye candy clock for refresh countdown
- a nice reputation graph as list header !
- the C++ launcher and resource system for easy deploy and use
- trick to remove antialiasing on phones (to avoid glitches)

[image: The mandatory screenshot]

[Link to the source repository](https://gitorious.org/apps-4-me/staq-me)

Answer (score 1):

New release !

- brand new UI
- now show recent activity
- can get the last 100 items in each category instead of 30 previously
- now shows more networks

[image]

Source code on Gitorious (see previous posts)

Answer (score 0):

I've been a long time without updating my StackOverflow client. So now it's done : new UI (looks liek my other apps), new features (full post/comments view), and better graphics/perfs...

Code is on  https://gitorious.org/apps-4-me/staq-me

[image: And the mandatory screenshot :]

Enjoy !